# How do I create a Favorite Contacts shortcut on Droid X?

Tags: contacts, motorola-droid-x, contact-shortcut

On the motorola Droid X there is a favorite contacts shortcut. I'd like to add this on another screen but I can't figure out how to create a new one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

while all of the above is true, you can simply click menu -> add -> shortcut -> dialer -> favorites to recreate the shortcut if you accidenatlly delete it.  that is if you are talking about the little red icon with the star that takes you to the favorites tab in the dialer.

Answer (score 1):

- "long touch" on the screen (the wallpaper) so the *Add to Home screen* option opens.
- touch *Motorola widgets*
- touch *Contact quick tasks*
- choose the contact you want to add
- choose the contact method(s)
- done!

Answer (score 0):

Some widgets might only be able to be placed once. If you only want one instance of it, but on another screen, just long click (click on the widget and keep your click/pressure on it or keep your finger pressed to the screen) till you have control of it. On my Android device I feel a vibrate and the widget shakes on the screen. Then just move it where ever you want. To go to another screen hold the widget to the edge of that screen and you should be on the the next screen.

Another tip that might be easier than moving apps and widgets on homescreens, just long click on them till you have control and remove them by dragging to the bottom of the screen. Then go to the screen you want and add it. Long click on an empty space of the homescreen and choose "widgets" then find your widget and add it.

Update:
So at the very top of my widget list is something that says, "Get more HTC widgets". You could see if you have that. Not sure if Motorola has their own option there or not.

Also try looking at your widget list and then see if you have "Contacts" or "People". On my phone I have "People" and that allows me to add one of those favorite listings for my contacts.

Comment: I know how to add widget and manage widgets. My question is how to add the favorite contacts shortcut/widget/whatever it is.

Comment: Have you ever had that widget on your phone before? I know HTC has a favorite contact widget, but it is a sense widget and would not work on a Droid of any kind without some modification. If so, if Motorola has there own version, I would think you could just follow the directions I wrote in my answer for adding a widget. It should show up in the listing of widgets.

Comment: The widget is already on the screen and it doesn't show up in any of the lists.

Comment: So at the very top of my widget list is something that says, "Get more HTC widgets". You could see if you have that. Also try looking at your widget list and then see if you have "Contacts" or "People". On my phone I have "People and that allows me to add one of those favorite listings.